# Errors generating ipa or xcarchive ( Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it? )

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ipa, xcarchive

We have some errors when we are generating the ipa or xcarchive file with some files from an external framework, in which the error indicates that the file does not exist in that path and we have verified that it does exist.

We have tried several proposed solutions, such as excluding the arm64 architecture from the targets, modifying the skip install value to YES... and we did not find the solution, we reached the point of generating the xcarchive and the ipa, but then the validation failed, since it is not well generated.

Finally, indicate that the build can be done and the app can be launched on the emulator or physical device without any problem.

Error example:
**/XXXXXFramework/XXXXXFramework/XXXXXAuthenticator.m Cannot find build input file: '/Users/XXXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXX-ddgeeowfzpsicugtbwaxtotdvxqk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediatesBuildProducts_XXXX/Indextallation/ /.. /Frameworks/XXXXXFramework.framework/Modules/module.modulemap'.

Did you forget to declare this file as the result of a script pass or custom build rule that produces it?**

Any ideas?

Environment:

- macOS Ventura 13.2.1
- Xcode 14.2